# Python: problem constructing an algorightm using list (TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'type' and 'int')

Tags: python

Here is what I wanted to do:

-An list V with random numbers, the quantity of numbers is given by the user

-An list P with the same quantity of numbers as of list V, but only 0's and 1's, these match the list V ( if the number is even on List V, it shows 0, if the number is not even, it shows 1)

I tried to solve this, but I got the error of **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'type' and 'int'**; how can I do this without getting it? here's my code:

```
import random

list_V = [random.randint (1,100) for i in range (1,dim +1)]

print(list_V)

list_P =[x for x in list_V if isinstance(x, (int))]

divider = 2

list_P =[int % divider]

print(list_P)
```

Comment: What is `list_P =[int % divider]` supposed to do? What do you think `int` refers to in that case? Why are you overwriting `list_P` in that line, without even reading any values from the list that you created right before?

Comment: Change `list_P =[int % divider]` to `list_P = [x % divider for x in list_P]`.

Comment: Where is *dim* defined?

Comment: @RandomDavis my bad, code was bad there, it was supposed to be  `list_P = list.copy(list_V)`

Using your advice @Samwise, i was able to fix the problem, and it works all perfectly now,thanks for the assist guys!

Comment: @JCaesar by mistake i didn't copy all code, but dim is defined on the very start, and it takes the values that user inputs, but Samwise advice already fixed my problem, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int` refers to the `int` type, not a particular int that you can apply mathematical operators to, or all of the ints in a particular list, or anything like that.  The syntax you want is `[x ... for x in ...]`.

Note that the comprehension where you filter `list_V` to only `int` instances is not necessary, because `random.randint` can only ever return `int`s in the first place.

```
import random

dim = int(input("How many numbers? "))

V = [random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(dim)]
P = [x % 2 for x in V]

print(V)
print(P)
```

```
How many numbers? 10
[64, 58, 24, 43, 69, 58, 16, 2, 54, 55]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```